Report Error - RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'brow.B.L.004': Input to rig type must be a chain of 2 or more Incorrect armature for type 'stretchy_chain'
Report Error - RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'brow.B.L.004': Input to rig type must be a chain of 2 or more Incorrect armature for type 'stretchy_chain'
I'm really new to blender and character rigging. I was following closely to a tutorial, or so I thought. Because when I went to generate the rig, I got this (above) error message.
I searched as best as I could to see if anybody had the same or similar problem. While their were a couple that were similar, it wasn't anything that I found helped with my issue.
I wouldn't be surprised if its the most easiest solution or something so obvious....
Thanks in advance!

This error concerns this bone:
In Rigify, each bone that gives you special controllers (when generated) is defined by a specific Rigify type. To see what type a bone has, you can go into pose mode and select the bone you want. In its bone properties, under "Rigify Type", you'll be able to see wich one it is. Here is the rigify type of brow.B.L.004:

Some Rigify types are quite fiddly, and will give you errors if you make a small mistake. In our case, the skin.stretchy_chain type requires you to have at least a chain of 2 or more bones.
The Rig type is applied on brow.B.L.004, that means it is the first bone of the chain. So we must have an other bone after it for the rig type to work.

In rigify's face bones, the brow.B.L.004 bone is followed by the nose.L bone, (the second bone of the chain). This nose bone is supposed to be connected and parented to the brow bone. You probably unparented it, disconnected it or you simply deleted it. Also, the tail of brow.B.L.004 and the head of nose.L must be perfectly aligned (as circled is the screenshot), otherwise you'll get an error.

note also that certain bones tail and head positions need to be exactly the same as their related bones. This becomes an issue when you move the bones around to match a custom face mesh. (using ctrl+S to ove the cursor to the target position and then the bone tails/head is a good way to align everything up correctly)
