RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'lid1.B.L': Input to rig type must be a chain of 2 or more bones. Incorrect armature for type 'stretchy_chain'
I am facing some issues with Rigify while building a character. I need to create an animation with it for a school project, and I decided to use Rigify because it's supposed to be simpler, or at least I thought it was.
My character has some parts that don't need very elaborate movement since it is very simple. Because of this, I ended up watching a tutorial to use only some parts of Rigify and skip those that would be unnecessary.

After a while, the problem you see on the screen started to appear, and I tried various ways to solve it, but I don't have much knowledge in Blender. I will leave the file below so that anyone who can help can have an easier view of what it could be, because I simply have no idea.

AnimationV1
I tried changing the bone types, tried matching some of these bones with what would be the complete Rigify, but nothing worked. Actually, one thing that did work was removing the bone types related to the eye, but even though it worked, it ends up losing the custom shapes, which would make the animation more difficult.
If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful.

Does this help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/316440/report-error-rigify-error-bone-brow-b-l-004-input-to-rig-type-must-be-a-ch?rq=1 ?

Further comment:  I'm no expert on Rigify, but comparing the ring of bones round your eyes against the ones in the standard rigify armature, all the bones in the standard ring connect head-to-tail right round the eye whereas the directions of the ones in your armature are reversed at the corners of the eyes.
